# Create Spacing with Percentage Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My problem is that I have four Buttons on the screen, I used a PercentageRelativeLayout to place them where I want them and everything was working great.
They even resize!
However, when they do resize, the Buttons start touching each other, and when I make it so they do not touch each other on a tablet, when I go back to a phone the space is too far apart.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could create a spacing that could work on all devices?

Because I thought that PercentageRelativeLayouts were the perfect solution to get things to resize, without using any LinearLayout and it is not working out the way I thought.

Below is my code

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#696969">

<ImageButton
    app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="9%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="21%"
    android:background="#00ff0000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/opt1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:id="@+id/purpleButton"
    android:layout_align="@+id/option1"
    android:longClickable="false" />

<ImageButton
    app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="9%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="58%"
    android:background="#00ff0000"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/opt2"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:id="@+id/option2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:longClickable="false" />
<ImageButton
    app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="50%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="58%"
    android:background="#00ff0000"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/opt3"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:id="@+id/option3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:longClickable="false" />
<ImageButton
    app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="50%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="21%"
    android:background="#00ff0000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/option4"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:id="@+id/opt4"
    android:longClickable="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Pick an Answer"
    android:id="@+id/pickLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="7%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="15%"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="12%"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="00"
    android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textSize="72sp"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: Post your current layout.

Comment: @FlyingPumba Just added the layout

Comment: @Rotwang when I use dps the view never resizes, it always stays the exact same size no matter what the screen size is

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:weightSum="1"` on the outside layout and `android:layout_weight="0.25"` for the inside layouts.

Comment: weights belong to LinearLayouts **only**